# Plotly: multiple x and y axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to plot the follow 'toy data' with two different x axis and two different y axis. When I try to plot it, it shows the two x-axis and two y-axis, but only plots **one trace**.

Suggestions?

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    data_x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10]
    data_x2 = [0,10,20,30,40,60,100]
    data_y1 = [0, 3555, 6114, 7395, 8016, 9130, 8646]
    data_y2 = [1, 1.2, 1.18, 1.18, 1.22, 1.28, 1.52]

    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x1, y=data_y1, xaxis="x", yaxis="y"))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x1, y=data_y2, xaxis="x", yaxis="y2"))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x2, y=data_y1, xaxis="x2", yaxis="y"))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x2, y=data_y2, xaxis="x2", yaxis="y2"))

    fig.show()
```

(trace1 is not hidden under trace3, but should overlap).
[image: plot produced]

Comment: Please read this link https://plotly.com/python/subplots/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of boilerplate code is necessary for this one and this is different for `xaxis` and `yaxis`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data_x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10]
data_x2 = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 100]
data_y1 = [0, 3555, 6114, 7395, 8016, 9130, 8646]
data_y2 = [1, 1.2, 1.18, 1.18, 1.22, 1.28, 1.52]

fig=make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])  # You need to create subplots figure with only one plot with the proper spec.
fig.update_layout(xaxis2= {'anchor': 'y', 'overlaying': 'x', 'side': 'top'})  # set the location and properties of the xaxis2

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x1, y=data_y1), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x1, y=data_y2), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x2, y=data_y1), secondary_y=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data_x2, y=data_y2), secondary_y=True)

# for some reason reference to the x2 xaxis must be done after adding the trace
fig.data[2].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.data[3].update(xaxis='x2')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out! I tried a lot of things, but the re-reference after adding the trace was not something I thought of.